# Laravel - referencing the class

Tags: php, laravel, coding-style

I've been reading a lot of documentation for Laravel during last week for the sake of learning what kind of beast it is.

I noticed one thing that whenever somebody references some class he references to it as string, e.g.:

```
  public function user()
  {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
  }
```

Pay attention to `'App\User'`

Taken from here  https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#polymorphic-relations

I wonder why don't  they reference it as `App\User::class` ?

In this case it's easier to type and support the code, because it's easier later to follow the class pressing Ctrl+B. Also refactoring is easier and it's harder to make a mistake because IDE will warn you that class doesn't exist if you make a typo.

I see no reasons to reference class User as `'App\User'` instead of `App\User::class`.

Do you see any?

Comment: In this case: do whatever floats your goat! It should be the same. A good IDE should also warn you about namespace / class typo's though.

Comment: The special ::class constant is available in PHP version >= 5.5.0. So for earlier version 'App\User' is used. You can use whatever you like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The actual string is used to illustrate that it is the full class name of the related model. You can very easily use `Model::class`. The example in the docs is explicit and removes any potential guess work from someone reading that argument.

Answer (score 1):

Taking from PHP doc [Class Constants](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.constants.php):

> The special ::class constant are available as of PHP 5.5.0, and allows for fully qualified class name resolution at compile, this is useful for namespaced classes:

This means that using `User::class` will at runtime resolve to `'App\User'` according to the example you gave. So the choice is yours.

On a personal note, In order to avoid typographical mistakes with strings I prefer to use the class constant resolution, and also I can easily check the usage from my IDE.

Also I do not have to memorise the namespace of the class I am using.

Apart from these benefit, I do not see any difference unless there is performance difference which obviously does not seem so.